# Where is the type of plastic stamped on my 2002 Pontiac Grand Prix front bumper cover?

Tags: pontiac

I want to try to repair my 2002 Grand Prix's front bumper cover with a plastic welder, but all the labels are faded and I can't figure out where the type of plastic is stamped.  Does anyone know exactly where to look?

Edit: I found a reference that says what type of plastic is used, but I'd still like to know where to look to find it stamped on the bumper itself.

According to [Urethane Supply Company](http://www.urethanesupply.com/bumperid.php):

> 1997-2003 Pontiac Grand Prix (fwd) GT|GTP; SE/2nd design Front TPO or
>   TEO (Thermo Plastic Olefin)

Answer (score 1):

If all the labels are faded or removed then you will have to refer to the main dealer for exact information of your bumpers composition or indexing. A second line would be to query the plastic welding rods available to buy are listed by the supplier as compatable with your vehicle. A third option would be a vehicle dismantlers as they would need to stream components for streaming when re-cycling. They would possibly be aware of any distinguishing marks on various components to do the re-cycling.